# Python: Is there a substitute for missing "print at" to a given line/column (Windows10)?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I try to produce text-lines, which all start in the same line at the same place (=overwriting). Therefore print() should not start in a new line as usual.Other program languages have easy solutions: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Cursor_positioning
Text-line overwriting not possible:

- using \r in the string has no effect (#1)
- first strip() and then put \r to the string has no effect (#2)
- ANSI-Escape-Sequence print("\033[6;3HHello") could do the job, but this is not recognized in Windows: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Cursor_positioning#Python
- A workaround shown on the same side didn't work at all and is a mass and seems not to be the concise way of python code.

> ```
> print("Good Morning!\rGood Evening!")   #1
> a = "Good Morning!" #2
> a = a.strip()
> print (a + "\r")
> print("Good Evening")
> ```

Comment: Update: I also tried pprint, was not successful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is pretty unfortunate in terms of this kind of operations. From my experience - the only solution is `curses`:

install by:

`pip install windows-curses`

```py
>>> import curses
>>> import time
>>> def print_inline(window):
...     x=["Good Morning!\nGood Evening!", "Good Morning!", "Good Morning!".strip(), "Good Evening"]
...     for el in x:
...         window.erase()
...         window.addstr(el)
...         window.refresh()
...         time.sleep(2)
...
>>> curses.wrapper(print_inline)
```

(I set up delay time to 2 seconds)

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html)

Comment: Curses Successfully installed pip-19.2.3. - if I run the suggested code I get an error from inside the curses-module: <br/>File "C:\Users\kadau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\eigene\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(print_inline)
  File "C:\Users\kadau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 73, in wrapper
    stdscr = initscr()
  File "C:\Users\kadau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 30, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Comment: Hm, looks like your stdout is None. Where do you run your code from? Command line, notebook?

Comment: It's the IDLE-Output-Window of Windows10. (Thanx for your help!)

Answer (score 0):

Command-line applications à la Turbo Pascal era aren't really (a native) thing in Python.

Try `windows-curses` or `rich`.